# Applications of Abel's angular theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I am currently working on the "Abel's angular convergence theorem", which I recall the statement here :

---

**Theorem :** Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n$ be a power series of radius of convergence equal to $1$. Let $\theta_0 \in \left[ 0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right[$ and define $$\Delta_{\theta_0} = \lbrace z \in D(0,1) \text{ }| \text{ } \exists \rho > 0,  \theta \in  \left[- \theta_0, \theta_0 \right], z=1-\rho e^{i\theta}\rbrace$$
If the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n$ converges, then
$$\lim_{z \rightarrow 1 \\ z \in \Delta_{\theta_0}} f(z) = \sum_{n =0}^{+\infty} a_n.$$

---

My question is simple : do you know an application of this theorem ? In particular, do you know an application where the "angular" part is used ?

Everytime this theorem is mentionned, I read as an application that you can deduce the relations
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \ln(2), \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{or} \quad \quad \quad \quad \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

but I think these examples are really bad because you don't need this theorem for them, since the series $\sum \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} x^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}x^n$ are clearly uniformly convergent over $[0,1]$.

So, does someone know a case where this theorem is really needed ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe it comes up in cluster sets for complex functions. See the paragraph beginning with "The other path, in which there were many more publications" in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3114828/13130), especially angular cluster set results in the two books and the dissertation (freely available on the internet) that I cite. However, I don't know much about this particular topic and don't have time now to look through those two books (which I have print copies of) and the dissertation.

Comment: Here is a nice illustration : http://robert.rolland.acrypta.com/telechargements/exercices/OnAbelAngularTheorem.pdf