# Reference Request: Classifying Cluster Points of Essential Discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, continuity

Let $n\in\mathbb N$, $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $a<b$, and a continuous function $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R^n$ be given. Now the following holds true:

> The set of accumulation points of $f$ at the boundary of the domain (say, at $a$)
> $$
> M:=\{x\in \mathbb R^n\,:\,\exists_{(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset(a,b)}\,\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=a\text{ and }\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)=x\}
> $$
> is either empty, or contains one element, or is uncountable.

Spoken more intuitively, what this should mean is that **if** a continuous function cannot be continuously extended to the closure of its domain ("$|M|\neq 1$"), **then** it either diverges to infinity ("$M=\emptyset$") or is "of the type" $\sin(\frac1x)$ ("$|M|=\aleph_1$").

Does anyone know of a citable reference which features such a result? My guess is that if some Analysis book features this result, it'd just list it as an exercise, *but* this would be better than nothing, of course. Any answer or comment is appreciated!

---

For the sake of rigor, here's a possible proof:

> Assume $|M|\geq 2$, that is, there exist $x_1,x_2\in M$ (with corresponding sequences $(s_n)_n$, $(t_n)_n$, respectively) as well as $R>0$ such that $x_2\not\in B_R(x_1)$. W.l.o.g. we may assume that $s_1>t_1>s_2>t_2>\ldots$ (e.g., by choosing appropriate subsequences). The idea is that given any ball which separates $x_1$ and $x_2$, $f$ has to cross the boundary infinitely many times so the intermediate value theorem plus compactness of balls/spheres in finite dimensions yields a new element of $M$.
>
> Let $r\in(0,R)$. Now by definition of $M$ there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that
> $$
> f(s_n)\in B_R(x_1) \quad\text{ and }\quad f(t_n)\not\in B_R(x_1)
> $$
> for all $n\geq N$. This is where we use continuity of $f$ by applying the intermediate value theorem: for every $n\geq N$ there exists $\tau_n\in (t_n,s_n)$ such that the function intersects the sphere of radius $r$, that is, $f(\tau_n)\in S_r(x_1)$. This yields a sequence $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which converges to $a$ such that $(f(\tau_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a subsequence of $S_r(x_1)$. But we are in finite dimensions so $S_r(x_1)$ is compact -- thus there exists a subsequence $(\tau_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $(f(\tau_{n_k}))_{k\in\mathbb N}$ converges with limit also on $S_r(x_1)$, denoted by $x_r$. But this all we needed because $x_r\in M$ (by definition of $M$) and $r\in(0,R)$ was chosen arbitrarily, so by injectivity of $r\mapsto x_r$ the set $\{x_r:r\in(0,R)\}\subset M$ is uncountable. $\;\square$

Comment: I don't have time to think about this now, but my answer to [Name for multi-valued analogue of a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3114828/13130), especially the references for cluster sets of complex-valued functions. Possibly relevant -- a glance at Collingwood's book (middle of p. 2) says that if $f$ is continuous on an open subset of the complex plane, then the cluster set of $f$ at a point where that subset is locally connected is either a point (hence has cardinality $1)$ or a continuum (hence has cardinality $\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0}).$ **(continued)**

Comment: Incidentally, the cluster set of a function is always a closed set, and thus will have cardinality $\mathfrak c$ if it is uncountable. Thus, the cardinal number $\aleph_1,$ regardless of whether the continuum hypothesis is assumed, does not need to be mentioned.

Comment: Indeed, the result in Collingwood you mentioned seems to be just what I was looking for! (In his setting he allows for functions with complex *or real* domain). Interestingly, the result seems to hold for any locally connected metric space as co-domain -- and not just the case $\mathbb R^n$ which I mentioned above. *(cont.)*

Comment: The only restriction he seems to impose is that the range of $f$ has to be bounded, which is crucial for connectedness of the the cluster set (but not for it being a continuum). For unbounded functions the connectedness result should continue to hold if one works in the compactification of the co-domain (e.g., the cluster set could consist of two half-lines which are "connected at infinity"). Either way feel free to post the proposed reference as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(edited and extended version of previously posted comments)* Collingwood/Lohwater’s 1966 book [**The Theory of Cluster Sets**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000CNB3H) says (middle of p. 2) that if $f:D \rightarrow {\mathbb C}$ and $D$ is an open subset of the complex plane ${\mathbb C},$ then the cluster set of $f$ at a point $z_0$ belonging to the (topological) boundary of $D$ such that $D$ is locally connected at $z_0$ is either a point (hence has cardinality $1)$ or a continuum (hence has cardinality $\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0}).$ A similar observation $(D$ is a Jordan domain bounded by a simple closed curve) is made in the middle of p. 1 of Noshiro’s 1960 book [**Cluster Sets**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540025162). See also p. 10 of James Reid Calhoun’s 1969 Ed.D. dissertation [**An Introduction to Cluster Set Theory**](https://shareok.org/bitstream/handle/11244/32738/Thesis-1969D-C152l.pdf), which unlike (as far as I know) the two books I previously mentioned, is freely available on the internet.

I don’t know much about these particular results, but I imagine they had been known many years before 1960, and I also suspect that there is a fair amount of research (some of which is likely covered in these references, but I haven’t checked them for this) into all kinds of refinements, generalizations, and variations of results related to the connectivity and continuum’ness of cluster sets.

Incidentally, the cluster set of a function is always a closed set, and thus will have cardinality $\mathfrak c$ if it is uncountable. Thus, the cardinal number ${\aleph_1},$ regardless of whether the continuum hypothesis is assumed, does not need to be mentioned.

Finally, my answer to [Name for multi-valued analogue of a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3114828/13130) gives some pointers to the vast literature involving cluster sets. I have an annotated bibliography (chronologically ordered) of cluster set papers and books (currently 391 items, 280 pages) that I add to from time to time when my interest and free time are sufficient, if you’re interested (send me [an email](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile)).